# Fabric SDK Crash [ANSAnswersController logCrashEvent:]

Tags: ios, twitter-fabric

Fatal Exception: NSInvalidArgumentException
*** +[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:options:error:]: value parameter is nil

Foundation +[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:options:error:] + 84

ProjectName -[ANSWriteEventOperation logLineWithTimestamp:eventName:payloadDictionary:] + 72

ProjectName -[ANSWriteEventOperation generateFormattedLogLineWithMetdata:timestamp:] + 142

ProjectName -[ANSWriteEventOperation initWithEvent:metadata:logFileUrl:] + 200

ProjectName 
__38-[ANSAnswersController logCrashEvent:]_block_invoke + 600

Foundation  **NSBLOCKOPERATION_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK** + 8

Comment: I have exactly the same issue on my apps ! I use the latest SDK.

Comment: What the Crashlyitcs version you are using. I am facing the same issue on Crashlytic 3.8.1 and Fabric 1.6.8 May be we can use an older stable version as a temporary fix.

Comment: My Crashlyitcs version is 3.8.1. It's crash on both iOS7, iOS9, iOS10.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This has been fixed in 3.8.2 as per the Crashlytics developers. See this speicific developer comment https://twittercommunity.com/t/crash-io-answers-eventqueue-nsoperation-qos-background/74765/7

Comment: I have the same issue with 3.8.2, on both iOS 10 and 9

Comment: so, It's can confirm to fabric's issues. My boss said we will update to latest version.

Comment: We're getting that crash on iOS7 devices. I'm publishing with 3.8.3 right now, hoping that it is fixed.